# How to display an output on the same line after taking an input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on java and I want to print a variable after taking an input (on the same line).
I have already tried backslash b ("\b") but it doesn't works.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
byte number = scanner.nextByte();
System.out.println("\b");
System.out.println(number);
```

The output is:

```
Enter a number: 23 //input

23 //output
```

I have also tried:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
byte number = scanner.nextByte();
System.out.println("\b" + number);
```

But it doesn't works either.

Comment: Use [`System.console()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html). Not sure whether it fits.

Comment: @JoopEggen Where do I need to use it?

Comment: Turned it into an answer. If you want to do more terminal like work,  take a look at the **jline** answer.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` needs an enter key to know when to finish the line, so console output will always start from a new line. You might need to resort to other library like [jline](https://github.com/jline/jline3) to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [java.io.Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

```
    Console con = System.console(); // null when there is no console like in the IDE.

    // Password without echo of entered char:
    char[] password = con.readPassword("Enter password: ");
    con.printf("Your password '%s' was correct.%n", new String(password));
    Arrays.set(password, ' '); // Normally done to not linger the password in memory.

    String answer = con.readLine("%nEnter a number between %d and %d: ", -128, 127);
    byte number = Byte.parseByte(answer);
    con.printf("Your number was %d, unsigned %d.%n", number, number & 0xFF);
```

***Elaboration***

- `readPassword` and `readLine` come in two overloaded forms. A pure read,
  and here with a prompt written first. The prompt is in String.format form,
  so it is a template string with `%` place holders, and parameters.
- `printf` is pure write; also with format. The format `%n` is needed here for a newline.

**Password** I gave for completeness: one unbeatable reason not to use Scanner on System.in. Note the correct usage: password as `char[]`, not `String`. A String is immutable, can be shared. It will linger in memory till the garbage collector makes its round. Meanwhile a virus might check that memory. But as char array one might clear its content after processing.
(Here I did nothing and accepted any "password.")

The only caveat of `System.console()` it might give null: when in the IDE, when not in the command window.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is happening here.